# Pandas: different indexing performances with same list

Tags: python, pandas

```
last5_ls = range(-5, 0, 1)
last25_ls = range(-25, 0, 1)
data = data.groupby('stockid')
data_last5 = data.nth(last5_ls)
data_last25 = data.nth(last25_ls)
close25_dict = {}
close5_dict = {}
```

#### Option A: about 1 min

```
stockid_ls = data_last25.index.drop_duplicates().tolist()
for sid in stockid_ls:
    if len(data_last25.loc[sid, 'close']) >= 25:
        close25_dict[sid] = data_last25.loc[sid, 'close'].tolist()
        close5_dict[sid] = data_last5.loc[sid, 'close'].tolist()
```

#### Option B: about 25s

```
stockid_ls = data_last5.index.drop_duplicates().tolist() 
for sid in stockid_ls:
    if len(data_last25.loc[sid, 'close']) >= 25:
        close25_dict[sid] = data_last25.loc[sid, 'close'].tolist()
        close5_dict[sid] = data_last5.loc[sid, 'close'].tolist()
```

The results of `data_last5.index.drop_duplicates().tolist()`  and `data_last25.index.drop_duplicates().tolist()` are identical.

However, if I use them as loop list, the former is much faster. Why this happend?

---

**data_last25's examples**:

```
    close   transtime
stockid         
000001.SH   3145.7724   2017-02-07 11:25:00
000001.SH   3146.2715   2017-02-07 11:30:00
000001.SH   3145.4279   2017-02-07 13:05:00
000001.SH   3146.0700   2017-02-07 13:10:00
000001.SH   3145.5921   2017-02-07 13:15:00
000001.SH   3144.9807   2017-02-07 13:20:00
000001.SH   3141.3619   2017-02-07 13:25:00
000001.SH   3142.4082   2017-02-07 13:30:00
000001.SH   3141.7696   2017-02-07 13:35:00
000001.SH   3144.6115   2017-02-07 13:40:00
000001.SH   3144.9876   2017-02-07 13:45:00
000001.SH   3146.0163   2017-02-07 13:50:00
000001.SH   3145.1942   2017-02-07 13:55:00
000001.SH   3146.9230   2017-02-07 14:00:00
000001.SH   3147.7423   2017-02-07 14:05:00
000001.SH   3146.1607   2017-02-07 14:10:00
000001.SH   3145.6695   2017-02-07 14:15:00
000001.SH   3148.0311   2017-02-07 14:20:00
000001.SH   3150.0356   2017-02-07 14:25:00
000001.SH   3150.7101   2017-02-07 14:30:00
000001.SH   3149.4439   2017-02-07 14:35:00
000001.SH   3148.4014   2017-02-07 14:40:00
000001.SH   3147.6509   2017-02-07 14:45:00
000001.SH   3147.9084   2017-02-07 14:50:00
000001.SH   3150.6996   2017-02-07 14:55:00
000001.SZ   9.2900  2017-02-07 11:25:00
000001.SZ   9.2800  2017-02-07 11:30:00
000001.SZ   9.2800  2017-02-07 13:05:00
000001.SZ   9.2800  2017-02-07 13:10:00
000001.SZ   9.2800  2017-02-07 13:15:00
000001.SZ   9.2800  2017-02-07 13:20:00
000001.SZ   9.2800  2017-02-07 13:25:00
000001.SZ   9.2800  2017-02-07 13:30:00
000001.SZ   9.2800  2017-02-07 13:35:00
000001.SZ   9.2800  2017-02-07 13:40:00
000001.SZ   9.2800  2017-02-07 13:45:00
000001.SZ   9.2900  2017-02-07 13:50:00
000001.SZ   9.2800  2017-02-07 13:55:00
000001.SZ   9.2800  2017-02-07 14:00:00
000001.SZ   9.2800  2017-02-07 14:05:00
000001.SZ   9.2900  2017-02-07 14:10:00
000001.SZ   9.2900  2017-02-07 14:15:00
000001.SZ   9.2900  2017-02-07 14:20:00
000001.SZ   9.2900  2017-02-07 14:25:00
000001.SZ   9.3000  2017-02-07 14:30:00
000001.SZ   9.3000  2017-02-07 14:35:00
000001.SZ   9.2800  2017-02-07 14:40:00
000001.SZ   9.2900  2017-02-07 14:45:00
000001.SZ   9.2800  2017-02-07 14:50:00
000001.SZ   9.2900  2017-02-07 14:55:00
```

**data_last5's examples**:

```
    close   transtime
stockid         
000001.SH   3149.4439   2017-02-07 14:35:00
000001.SH   3148.4014   2017-02-07 14:40:00
000001.SH   3147.6509   2017-02-07 14:45:00
000001.SH   3147.9084   2017-02-07 14:50:00
000001.SH   3150.6996   2017-02-07 14:55:00
000001.SZ   9.3000  2017-02-07 14:35:00
000001.SZ   9.2800  2017-02-07 14:40:00
000001.SZ   9.2900  2017-02-07 14:45:00
000001.SZ   9.2800  2017-02-07 14:50:00
000001.SZ   9.2900  2017-02-07 14:55:00
000002.SH   3297.8762   2017-02-07 14:35:00
000002.SH   3296.7849   2017-02-07 14:40:00
000002.SH   3295.9991   2017-02-07 14:45:00
000002.SH   3296.2701   2017-02-07 14:50:00
000002.SH   3299.2052   2017-02-07 14:55:00
```

Comment: Please add an example of your data.

Comment: @Khris Just added the data examples, thanks.

Comment: So you are using `stockid` as your index and use `drop_duplicates` on that yielding the two identical lists, right? Since the `drop_duplicates` is the only difference between the two options have you timed how much time the `drop_duplicates` commands alone need?

Comment: @Khris `data_last5.index.drop_duplicates().tolist() ` : 7ms. `data_last25.index.drop_duplicates().tolist() ` : 12ms

Comment: I see. Have you measured the times in your question (25s and 1 min) in two separate runs or within the same run?

Comment: @Khris I measured them separately and got the different running times. So I'm curious about what other factors could make the difference.

Comment: I had the thought that if you had done it together then in the first run your dictionaries would have to be newly created (that is allocating new memory, creating keys, etc) while in the second run the already existing dictionary would just have gotten new values assigned. But if the difference is still there when doing it separately then it's not that.

Comment: You could try this: First `import copy`, then do `stockid_ls = copy.deepcopy(data_last25.index.drop_duplicates().tolist())` and `stockid_ls = copy.deepcopy(data_last5.index.drop_duplicates().tolist())`, then compare the times again.

Comment: Tried your code, and got the same peformance result as before.

Comment: Hmm. Since that line is the only line that is different between the two parts it has to be that, but apart from playing around with that I have no other ideas.

Comment: OK, thanks anyway.@Khris